# How to access array element returned from a object method in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, syntax

I have been using Perl for a while but is bothered by one syntax problem.
In some packages, a method can return an array. For example

```
$root->getlist();
```

Will return an array. Now I want to get the first element of the result. Of course I can do this:

```
my @results = $root->getlist();
if($results[0] =~ /wow/) {
    print "Qualified result";
}
```

However, this is very troublesome. Is there a way that I can combine the first line with second line? I tried this but failed.

```
if(${$root->getlist()}[0] =~ /wow/) {
    print "Qualified result";
}
```

Is there a way to do this quick?

A better example:
Consider this following package:

```
package Try;

sub new {
    my $package = shift;
    return bless({}, $package);
}

sub getList {
    return (1,2,3,4,5);
}

1;
```

Now I have a user pl file like this:

```
use lib '.';
use Try;
use strict;

my $obj = Try->new();
print ($obj->getList())[0];
```

Trying to run this script will result in:

> syntax error at perlarrayaccess.pl line 6, near ")["
>
> Execution of perlarrayaccess.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: That syntax error is because the first open parenthesis is parsed as the parentheses surrounding the arguments to `print`. Try `print $obj->getList()[0];` without the extra parenthesis and see if it works.

Comment: In addition to `use strict`, you should `use warnings`. If you did, you'd see that you are trying to call `print` as a function in the last example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( ( $root->get_list() )[0] =~ /wow/ ) {
    print "Qualified result";
}
```

Comment: Sorry it actually doesn't work. Like the sample code up there I just updated.

Comment: @pulseball, your example doesn't work because print is interpreted as a function call. `use warnings` to see what I mean. If you put it in the if block, like Chris, it will work... at least it did for me.

Comment: @gpojd Now I see. The () was interpreted as functions parenthesis. Lazy makes me scratch my head. lol.

Answer (score 2):

There's `wantarray` for that. In your `sub` returning the array, do:

```
sub getlist()
{
    my $self = shift;

    #  caller wants the full list
    if (wantarray) {
        # fetch all
        return @all_results;
    } else {
        # fetch only first result here.
        return $one_result;
    }
}
```

This would save you the overhead of fetching all results, when only the one is required. If it's another index you specifically need, write:

```
if ([$root->getlist]->[5] =~ /wow/) {
...
}
```

I know, perl is not about easy reading, but this one's more legible than `${$root->get}[0]`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make an array reference and dereference it to get fhe syntax right.

Comment: I agree with chris lutz, you can use chris J's method to pull one element, however I agree wholeheartedly that if there is to be nice behavior with one element AND different nice behavior for many elements, the onus can be on the `sub` to get it right. Especially if you are writing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($root->getlist()[0] =~ /wow/) {
    print "Qualified result";
}
```

Ought to work. The second thing that you tried treats the returned value as an array *reference* and tries to dereference it. The method just returns an array (or rather, a list - there is a difference), so you need to just access the element you want.

Comment: It doesn't work either, like the example in the updated question.

Comment: Is it not working in my sample code (with no extraneous parenthesis inside an `if` statement) or in some other context (like your added example)?

Comment: No it gives error. Actually Linus Kleen's method and Chris J's methods both work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl syntax you can just assign return value to a list of variables:

```
my ($result) = $root->getlist();
print "Qualified result" if $result =~ /wow/;
```

This is very basic Perl syntax that often used when you need to get few parameters in sub:

```
sub get_three_params {
    my ($foo, $bar, $baz) = @_;
}
```

Comment: This way requires two lines, which is not easier than what I mentioned. I want to access the returned value in one statement